# Android Studio 2.1 update downloading separate instance as Studio 32/64

Tags: android, android-studio

In Android Studio's earlier versions:
Whenever a new update was there, a patch sort of download was there with option to restart the Studio.
However, after 2.0 Updates, it is downloading separately (as pre installed package)- making two instances of Studio.

If I wish to update my current 1.X update directly to 2.X , how I can I do so without separate instance?

Answer (score 0):

After 3.0 release (and in some Google I/O discussion) , I learned that these versions are unstable, but contains some new features. So it is provided as separate bundle for the enthusiast who want to get used to/ try such features.